# Search on my asp.net page displays no records

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, repeater

I'm trying to search documents with an SP which looks like this

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spsearchdocuments]
@Name  nvarchar(50)

as

SELECT     dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
 dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
 dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,
   dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate,
 dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
FROM         dbo.DocumentInfo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
                      where DocumentInfo.ApproveID=3 and
 [DocName] like '%'+@Name+'%'
```

when i first check sp like 
[image]

it show records but when i call this sp in my project like this ...

```
public DataTable searchdcouments(string Name)
        {

            return db.ExecuteDataSet("spsearchdocuments", new object[] { Name }).Tables[0];
        }
```

and

```
protected void Btn_submits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {     
            Repeater4.DataSource = sear.searchdcouments(searz.Text);
            Repeater4.DataBind();        
        }
```

and when i search in project then it cannot show me any records..
[image]
where is the problem?any help?

Comment: What does `ExecuteDataSet` look like?

Comment: What does the code look like? when you step through, can you see the data in `Tables[0]` ?

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but have you tried replacing `"spsearchdocuments"` with `"dbo.spsearchdocuments"` in your call to ExecuteDataSet?

Comment: spsearchdocuments and dbo.spsearchdocuments is the same thing i thnk